# Issue versioning api calls

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an updated version of an api call.

**urls.py**

```
router.register(r'categories', views.CategoryViewSet)

router.register(r'categoriesv2', views.CategoryViewSetV2)
```

However, when I run the internal server, the autogenerated api root is as follows:

```
"categories": "http://10.0.5.119:8000/api/**categoriesv2**/",

"categoriesv2": "http://10.0.5.119:8000/api/categoriesv2/",
```

Why is "categories" also pointing to /categoriesv2/ and not /categories/? Any help would be appreciated please!

Comment: i don't know what is `autogenerated api` but any way best solution for new api version is `api/v2/route`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `register` as per [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) has three parameters:

mandatory arguments : `prefix` and `viewset` which you have already specified

Optional argument: `base_name`

> **base_name** - The base to use for the URL names that are created. If unset the basename will be automatically generated based on the queryset attribute of the viewset, if it has one. Note that if the viewset does not include a queryset attribute then you must set `base_name` when registering the viewset.

So the better way to do versioning is to create alternate router as below:

```
# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router_v2 = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'categories', views.CategoryViewSet)
router_v2.register(r'categories', views.CategoryViewSetV2)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))
    url(r'^api/v2/', include(router_v2.urls))
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!